# Basic JQuery Slider Work Around for Sliding effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using Basic JQuery SLider from the following site.

http://www.basic-slider.com/

I want slider to slide from left to right direction,it currently slides from right to left.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {          
      $('#myslider').bjqs({
        animtype      : 'slide',
        height        : 126,
        width         : 244,
        responsive    : true,
        randomstart   : true,
        showmarkers : false,
        hoverpause : false,
        nexttext :   '<img src="img/next-horizontal.png">',
        prevtext :   '<img src="img/prev-horizontal.png">',
        animduration : 350, // how fast the animation are
        animspeed : 3000, // the delay between each slide
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this option is not available as a configuration of Basic Slider.
You can fork the source code on github and try to implement it as new "animtype" or just hack the library to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the go variable in bjqs-1.3.js.

And also in this file you should get into the method

```
if(settings.animtype === 'slide')
```

and change the values of

```
resize_complete(function(){
                    go(false,state.currentslide);
                }, 200, "some unique string");
```

depends on slider effect.

Dont forget to download developer version of that script. It is included in the site that you gave us.

I hope that helps.